# Which GUI tools can export high quality LaTeX?

Tags: export

Publishers often complain internally about the bad quality of hand-written LaTeX.
Which graphical mathematical editors are able to export high quality LaTeX?

Let me add some criteria that I would personally use, but I am open for criteria that are important for others.

1. The generated LaTeX should obviously be human-readable and editable.
2. The code should compile without any (or a minimal number of) errors.
3. The code should be nicely formatted: lines of approximately the same
   lengths, properly indented environments.
4. A minimal number of extra definitions in the preamble and maybe some
   user preference for having none at all.
5. Reduced dependence on specific packages.
6. Rely on standard markup as much as possible and avoid obscure markup.

Comment: Perhaps add some criteria here for 'high quality' - e.g. avoiding `eqnarray`, `\rm`, strange mark-up

Comment: I might be tempted to suggest  a format for answers (as is done in the IDE question), e.g. that they should show the output for some defined mathematical aspects

Comment: Hmm, good point.  And good question actually.  What would _you_ consider to be high quality LaTeX?  I just report on what this publisher told me.  For one, I think that it just "looked" nice (proper indentation, lines of equal lengths, etc.).  TeXmacs puts some macros in the preamble, but not that many.  And then tries to keep the code as simple as possible, probably.

Comment: which publishers make which comments?   This question is running very close to the standard "opinion based" close reason, unless you have any actual facts or criterion by which to judge the output of different systems.

Comment: I am not in the head of the person who made that compliment.  What I can say is that TeXmacs indeed tends to produce purified and nicely indented LaTeX code. For conversions from other wysiwyg tools such as Word, I heard people complain about lots of superfluous styling commands.  But my question is indeed somewhat open.  I am open for criteria that are important for people other than me.

Comment: What is an "opinion based" close reason?  It seems fair to me to ask for further substantiation, but are we not allowed to have opinions on this network?  I find your behaviour extremely aggressive.  Should I interpret "close reason" as some kind of a thread?

Comment: "Lines of approximately the same length" rationally applies only to text blocks.  Math should be formatted (in the input) in a way that makes the structure of the math expression(s) maximally clear, which may lead to lines of wildly different length.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se 
Comment too long for a comment. See answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instinctively, there cannot be an answer.

Like: What is the best quality ink for writing an essay? Depends on whether I use a fountain-pen, and the humidity of where I am. (And on the paper.)

But can there be the possibility of an answer?

Some musings:

1 (a) Code sourcer (some process) and latex code (some output of the sourcer process) are not the same object/event. They are logically decoupled. Unrelated: reliance on deprecated code, visual style, technique/method and program logic-flow should be reduced, if reduction has a practical purpose and outcome. Note also: program logic-flow is polyvalent, so multiple solution methods are possible. Presumably, shortest token list is one HQ, or easiest-to-understand per unit time is another HQ (or both?). Or easiest to maintain/modify??

1 (b) The "visual grammar" syntax rules applied by one sourcer are not compulsorily identical to the rules applied by another sourcer, so multiple alternatives are allowed, much like the syntax of a phrase in English or French can be closer to or further away from the syntax of a phrase in Chinese or Japanese, yet all the visual phrases have the same "meaning" (latex PDF etc output is identical).

2 Code should compile. Unrelated: Reasonably quickly.

3 Why? Unrelated: other "visual grammars" may be better (or not) for different purposes. "Better" has multiple axes to compare against. One "style" won't meet all requirements fully all the time, when and since the axes pull in different directions.

4 Why? (Although everything can go in an input file.) If a publisher is not interested in the preamble, why can't they skip over it? If "definitions" relates to program logic-flow, see 1(a).

5 The system is open-ended. There are no borders. Packages can merge, split, be absorbed into the kernel, and/or emulated. And do other things besides. Package-dependency sounds like a publisher installation setup constraint rather than HQ.

6 "Standard markup": see 1(a); "obscure markup": if the question (as `X`) is: `How to increase the information transfer rate?` (from document to human), then questions 1, 3, 4, 5 and half of 6 are `Y`.

---

Example: if I have a document whose source cannot be modified in <5 min (if the source -- note: not the latex code -- is being created manually), then it is "clunky". Define the criteria of HQ (for publisher XYZ).

Example: nicely formatted code is junk if the output is junk (either physical or logical or both). But pretty junk.

Example: a measure of "publisher complexity", O(p), is needed. This will not automatically be identical to "transformational complexity" (say, into another human or machine language, or mathematical notation). Or any of the other complexities. So, then, question: what does the publisher want?

Answer (score -1):

I personally only use TeXmacs to write my mathematical articles.
A publisher once complimented me that my (automatically generated) LaTeX "source code" was much better than other papers that they routinely received.

Comment: So, you got the answer you were looking for? Or, is this supposed to be a part of the question?